# World currencies lookup table - with ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes?

Tags: c#, php, database, geolocation, lookup-tables

Where to get a database of world currencies?

It should contain the country along with the currency used in that currency.

i.e "CountryCode, CurrencyCode"

**Example**

```
US, USD
UK, GBP
AU, AUD
NZ, NZD
HK, HKD
```

Answer (score 2):

Full list of ISO country codes along with their 2 digit and 3 digit can be found here:
http://www.davros.org/misc/iso3166.txt

However this maybe of more use to you: 
http://www.commondatahub.com/live/geography/currency/country_currency_codes

ISO 3166 provides the country codes:
http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/

ISO 4217 provides currency codes:
http://www.iso.org/iso/currency_codes

There is a DB available here: http://www.mega-db.com.ar/Table/world_currencies  but it contains the ISO 3 digit country codes.
You could use this with the ISO 3166 (2 digit) codes, to produce the required dataset.